# Select from two tables - sort result by foreign and primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

1. Section: _id, name
2. Item: _id, name, section_id

I'm trying to sort result in a such way:

```
1 Section1
1 Item1 1
2 Item2 1
3 Item3 1
2 Section2
4 Item4 2
5 Item5 2
```

In other words - place items which belongs to section below the section itself.

Is it possible to achieve such result using just one query?

**EDIT**

For now I'm using `INNER JOIN`, but it's not completely suitable for my purposes: I need to know exact count of distinct sections inside query and it would be great if I'll be able to know the exact position of next section (for now I'm just sorting by `section_id` and looking for it changes)

Comment: Are you going to show what you've tried?

Comment: do you want the extra numbers you display, if so, from where are they derived?

Comment: It's possible, but I wouldn't normally regard this as a good idea. Why do you want to do it purely in SQL?

Comment: @MarkBannister because I'm caching data from server in a such way (sections contains items) and I need to display it in UI accordingly (I'll prefer to not dive inside details here). So, such output from database will be very useful.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev, are you waiting for a better answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this perhaps, [here is some fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b051/8)

```
select 
        s._id sid,
        s.name, 
        null iid
    from 
        section s
union all
select 
        i.section_id sid, 
        i.name, 
        i._id iid
    from
        item i
    order by
        sid, iid
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like

```
select section._id as sectionId,section.name, 0  as itemId
from section 
union
select item.section_id as sectionId, item.name, item._id as itemId
from item
order by sectionId, itemId
```